# How do I get out of the bed?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Right at the beginning of the game, Meowth comes into your room and attempts to wake you up. At this point, I assume I have to press some button to get out of bed, but the D-Pad or A button doesn't do anything, nor any of the other buttons. How do I get out of bed to start the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Pokemon Sun and Moon, Game Freak have moved away from a grid based movement system and as such, have disabled movement using the D-Pad. You now need to move the Circle Pad to move in game.

Pressing any direction on the Circle pad will make you leave the bed.

Comment: Note: The reason why you can no longer move with the D-Pad, is because it is now used to map ride Pokémon to it. It's similar to how you'd map the bike or fishing rod to the Select button in the old games.